# Zero/Sign extension in assembly without using MOVZX/MOVSX

Tags: assembly, binary, x86-16, sign-extension

I'm trying to do a zero or sign extension but without using `MOVZX` or `MOVSX`.
I basically want to mimic the said commands, but not use them. Is there a way to do it?
To add 0 from the left there's `SHR` but I'm not quite sure that it works the same because it changes the value...

I'm using Assembly 8086

Comment: See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58768040/417501) addressing different strategies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All x86-16 CPUs provide the `CBW` (8-bit to 16-bit) and `CWD` (16-bit to 32-bit) instructions.

If you want to do a "generic" sign extension (e.g. from 12-bit to 16-bit instead of from 8-bit to 16-bit), you might use the following algorithm that works on any CPU:

- Perform an `AND` to get the highest bit of the word to be extended
- Subtract the result from the original value twice or:
- Shift the result left by one and subtract it once from the original value

Example: Sign-extending `AX` from 12-bit to 16-bit:

```
; Ensure that the value is really a 12-bit value
AND AX, 0xFFF
; Extract the highest bit
MOV CX, AX
AND CX, 0x800
; Subtract that value twice
SUB AX, CX
SUB AX, CX
```

The code above may be simplified by working on the high byte of `AX` only (e.g. `AND AH, 0xF` instead of `AND AX, 0xFFF`).

Comment: Alternatively, shift left by the number of places you want to sign extend, then shift right arithmetically to copy the sign bit.

Comment: "...**not** from 12-bit to 16-bit instead of 8-bit as source..." Is this sentence correct? Why the word **not**?

Comment: @SepRoland Thanks. A mistake of mine. I'll correct it.

Comment: @fuz On an 8088 or 8086 a shift operation by N bits is a rather slow operation because those CPUs internally performed 1-bit shifts in a loop. And the question: "without `movsx`" makes only sense to me if the code should work on such old CPUs, too.

Comment: Alternatively: `XOR AX, 0x800; SUB AX, 0x800`

Comment: @njuffa: Oh cool, that trick might potentially be useful for SIMD sign-extension within vector elements, sometimes cheaper than shift left / arithmetic-right.  (Even if SSE4.1 `pmovsxbd` or whatever is available, you sometimes want to operate "in lane", especially with AVX2)